How to handle answers with security issues?
The most upvoted answer here appears to be quite dangerous advice. Exposing your wallet seed to an online tool might lead to all sorts of trouble, no?
What to do in cases like this? Comment/downvote/flag/meta post?

I'm not sure why it is particularly dangerous.  It involves getting a piece of code from somewhere and running it.  If the code is honest, you are ok (by design the code runs locally in the browser and doesn't send the wallet seed anywhere).  If the code is dishonest you are screwed.  The same would be true for any other piece of software you might download to accomplish your goal.

I agree it would be bad to use a truly "online" tool where you submit your seed to a server and it computes the address for you.  But this isn't that, although it presents a similar interface.

I would suggest editting the post with a large warning before the dangerous part, explaining the risk involved. If there is a large concern of safety and there is a safer alternative, I would also downvote the answer, and upvote the safer option. If the answer is outright and obviously destructive, you could flag it for deletion.

I added warnings as you suggested to two answers in that thread (suggested edits since I don't have enough rep, we'll see if they'll get approved).
